# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable :multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: python

I'm new to python, so sorry if there's a really obvious answer to this question. Here's my code:

```
def mult_of_3_or_5():
    for x in range(21):
        if x % 5 == 0:
            (x)
            continue
        elif x % 3 == 0:
            (x)


print(sum(mult_of_3_or_5()))
```

When I run it, the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" comes up. I've looked at other questions on Stack Overflow with a similar problem, but I still don't get what i can do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mult_of_3_or_5` isn't returning anything, so it's explicitly returning `None`

Comment: What would `(x)` be supposed to do??

Comment: You may need to re-read your study material on the use of `def`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(sum(mult_of_3_or_5()))
```

`sum()` expects to receive a sequence of items (typically a list) as its argument.

But the `mult_of_3_or_5()` function does not return anything, therefore it returns `None` by default.  `sum()` is trying to iterate over the value `None`, and that is your error.

It looks like you intended `mult_of_3_or_5()` to return a list of values between 0 and 20 that are multiples of 3 or 5.  But it doesn't do that.

Comment: What would you suggest to find the sum of the numbers? If you couldn't tell this is the first Project Euler problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function mult_of_3_or_5 returns nothing. Python will return NoneType as a default, even if not explicitly specified.

You try to sum the result the with sum(mult_of_3_or_5()) which will try to sum(NoneType). This is not possible because NoneType is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is:

```py
def mult_of_3_or_5():
    for x in range(21):
        if x % 5 == 0:
            yield x
        if x % 3 == 0: # I suspect you meant to count twice if both 3 and 5 are divisors, if not make it elif instead
            yield x


print(sum(mult_of_3_or_5()))
```

Which essentially will sum all multiples of 3 and 5, counting the number twice, in case it's multiple of both (eg. 15).

Returns `113`

You should familiarise yourself with concept of **generator** in python - which is what I introduced by the keyword `yield` here.
Unlike `return` it won't terminate the function, once called- which is essentially what *I understand* you want to achieve.

To read about the **generator**:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators